# Acceder a campos de arraylist individualmente

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo una clase llamada Producto() la cual tiene la siguiente forma:

```
public class Producto {

private String nombre;
private float precio;
private float iva;
private int unidades;

public Producto(String n, float p, float i, int u){

    this.nombre = n;
    this.precio = p;
    this.iva = i;
    this.unidades = u;
}
```

Y quiero crear un método mediante el cual pueda acceder y tratar los diferentes campos del Producto. He creado un arrayList sobre producto en el cual esta guardada la información de los productos que se importa desde un archivo de texto, los cuales se encuentran un producto por linea y nombre, precio, iva y unidades separados por #.

```
private ArrayList<Producto> productosImportados;
```

El problema es que este arraylist me guarda los productos, pero el producto entero en cada celda, es decir, en la celda i está todo lo relacionado con ese producto y no puedo tratar sus campos individualmente.
Tampoco puedo acceder a productosImportados.element(i)[j].
¿Alguna solución? Gracias.

Comment: porque los tienes en privados, crea sus getters and setters correspondientews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear los getter y setter (Encapsular) a tu clase producto y llamar tu producto segun su posicion en el arraylist con `myArrayList.get(index);` u obtener el id del producto con `myArrayList.indexOf(objetoProducto);`.

Ya cuando obtengas su id solo utilizas `myArrayList.set(id, objetoProductoModificado);` y ya actualizas los valores en tu ArrayList

Comment: Es verdad, me había olvidado de los getter y setter. Muchas gracias, voy a implementarlos y si me sigue dando problemas lo vuelvo a comentar.

Comment: He implementado los getter y setter pero sigo sin obtener lo que quiero. Lo que quiero hacer es poder usar los elementos por separado para poder, por ejemplo, mostrar una tabla por pantalla con todos los elementos. Si hago `productosImportados.get(index)`, me saca el producto entero (nombre precio iva unidades). En mi cabeza está `productoImportados.nombre.get(index)` pero ya veo que no existe. O por ejemplo, `if (productoImportados.precio == X)...` No se si me explico.

Comment: Intenta hacer esto:
'Producto prod = productosImportados.get(index);'
prod.getIva();

Comment: Vale, funciona pero no del todo. Me saca sólo los nombres pero de todos los productos, es como que no tiene en cuenta el get(i) (dentro de un for).

Answer (score 1):

Sólo tienes el constructor de la clase, te faltan los métodos para acceder a los atributos de la misma, tienes que crearlos.
Suena a un ejercicio de clase de programación. Tienes que trabajartelo.

Answer (score 1):

Es algo así lo buscas?

```
for (int i = 0; i<productos.size(); i++){
  System.out.println(productos.get(i).getNombre());
        if(productosImportados.get(i).getPrecio == x){
            //Lo que sea
        }
}
```

Comment: Ocurre lo mismo que arriba, saca solo el campo que quiero pero de todos los productos importados sin respetar el indice. No se, es raro...